# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los checkbox seleccionados para poder editarlos en javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Éste es mi código:

```
function BuscarHorario(horarioID, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado, domingo) {
   
    $("#titulo-Modal-Horario").text("EDITAR LOS DIAS");
    $("#HorarioID").val(horarioID);

   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../../Horarios/BuscarHorario',
        data: { HorarioID: horarioID, Lunes: lunes, Martes: martes, Miercoles: miercoles, Jueves: jueves, Viernes: viernes, Sabado: sabado, Domingo: domingo },
        success: function (horario) {
            $("#HoraInicio").val(horario.horaIniciostring);
            $("#HoraFin").val(horario.horaFinstring);
            $("#ProfesionalID").val(horario.profesionalID);
            $("#TiempoTurnos").val(horario.tiempoMostrar);
            $("#Lunes").val(horario.lunes);
            $("#Martes").val(horario.martes);
            $("#Miercoles").val(horario.miercoles);
            $("#Jueves").val(horario.jueves);
            $("#Viernes").val(horario.viernes);
            $("#Sabado").val(horario.sabado);
            $("#Domingo").val(horario.domingo);
            $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

Ese es el código de javascript, ya los días están Seleccionados pero me los trae vacíos a la hora de Editar